# Native Base and TabNavigator get active status in tabBarComponent

Tags: react-native, native-base, tabnavigator, react-native-tabnavigator

[image]

I am using Native Base and TabNavigator to display custom tabs.

How can I change the "active" property of the Button element to reflect the custom active tab?

Answer (score 0):

Solved by adding:

```
active={props.navigation.state.index === 0}
```

Here is the logged value:

[image]

Also, you can go to state.routes to get the list of the screens.